# wxPython Slider background colour incomplete change

Tags: python, wxpython

wxPython 2.8.10, Python 2.6.2, Windows 7 x64

So I am having a bit of a wxPython issue I am hoping someone can say where I am going wrong.  In my application I have Sliders where the background colour changes as you move the slider around.  I do this via SetBackgroundColour from within a EVT_SLIDER handler.  It mostly works, but I end up with a border of unchanged colour around the outer edge of the widget.

I have tried Refresh up the chain, RefreshRect on the top level Frame around the widget (and a few pixels further out), various combinations of Update and Layout, but nothing seems to erase it.  The best I have managed is if I use something like:

```
frame = wx.GetTopLevelParent(slider)
rect = slider.GetRect()
slider.ClearBackground()
slider.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(red,green,blue))
frame.RefreshRect(rect)
```

It will correctly draw the background box with the new colour without the border issue, but it will not repaint the slider itself.

However, if I click away so the focus is elsewhere, the border snaps to the new colour.

I could probably use an overlay or custom paint function but I am hoping there is something I am missing here that will get me the desired results.

Any suggestions?

(edited to add)
Looks like resizing the window manually corrects the issue, but Layout() does not.

It also functions correctly if you do the client size trick:

```
w,h = slider.GetClientSize()
slider.SetClientSize( (w+1,h) )
slider.SetClientSize( (w,h) )
```

Comment: try forcing it with `slider.Update()`

Comment: No effect.  I tried: slider.Update(), slider.GetParent().Update(), and wx.GetTopLevelParent(slider).Update()

Comment: Try calling Layout() on the widgets parent or the sizer that contains the slider

Comment: I tried having a loop the ran up the chain from slider to top level calling Layout() and Refresh() on every widget, still no effect.